# trying to build a url with full computer name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I get my full computer name (with domain) to show up in a url I'm constructing in my code?

**Updated:**

Ok so how do I utilize

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName("localhost").HostName
```

with existing

```
String myUrl = Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id = id }, "http");
```

to have the FQDN in my link on my page

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-get-the-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c

Comment: You could have multiple FQNs (Fully Qualified Names) for a single machine so this is not straight-forward. I take it you want the DNS name for the machine?

Comment: @chibacity - the DNS name sounds right I guess

Comment: @Cody Gray - I want to display a link on my page so a user can click on it but the link must have the dns included as part of the host name

Comment: again, what do you actually want? There's plenty of functions that return absolute url, relative url, then there's IIS bindings and Netbios name, etc. If It's FQDN, why don't you accept the answer below?

Comment: All I want to do is put a link in an email that a user can click on, but I need the link to have the full domain name and the port number included, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with Cody inasmuch as I'm not properly sure *how* you're trying to achieve *what* you want to, however, banking on the fact that *you* know this stuff then maybe we can be somewhat removed from the context of the practice and offer solutions for your to integrate, on such a basis, here is a thread which ought to interest you...

[How to find FQDN of local machine in C#/.NET ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-get-the-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c)