# Fully qualified domain name and port #

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a link in an email so our users can have a shortcut into the subject of interest. However, I need the link to contain the FDQN and the port number to be part of the link?

I am aware of the following statement but not sure if applicable or not because it doesn't show the port:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName("localhost").HostName
```

I've seen the following forum link:

[Does anyone know a way to get the FQDN of local machine in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-get-the-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c)

Does the port number need to be hard-coded?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port will not show, as it is not part of the domain name.

You will need to hard code (or use a configurable value) the port number if you are not using a standard one (i.e. 80 for http).