# Detect the name of the network the server is connected to

Tags: c#, .net

When developing an application at home or at work I need to comment the code that sets the **proxy on or off**. Because at home I am on a different network than at work, **at home I don't need to use the proxy**.

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(Settings.ProxyAddress, Settings.ProxyPort);
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
this.Proxy = proxy;
```

I would like to wrap this statement in a if-clause that determines the name of the network. Like

```
if(isCorporateNetwork) {.....set proxy...};
```

I tried to detect it with:

```
IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
```

But that results as an empty string. Probably because **my personal laptop** is **not a member of the domain**. *(However access to the network is granted by sending my credentials to the proxy, own devices are allowed to use the corporate network this way.)*

**How can I detect the name of the network that I am connected to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to lookup your IP-address using DNS. (If you got a private IP you need to get the public through STUN or similar)

(This is just a different approach since yours seems to be the way to go: [How to find FQDN of local machine in C#/.NET ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-get-the-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c))

Comment: If I need a public IP I need to get access to the proxy first ;) Wouldn't that be the same as wrapping it in a try catch and a retry then?