# How to get a simple computer name (without the domain name) out of a full computer name in c#?

Tags: c#, dns, hostname, fqdn

Can I get just a simple computer name (without the domain name) from a fully qualified name (can be with or without a domain name)? Is it possible for a computer name to have a dot (.) sign in it?

[(this question seems to be doing the reverse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-get-the-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No hostnames cannot contain a dot (reference [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) and [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) (see "ASSUMPTIONS") and [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13)). It is the delimiter between the hostname and the domainname. So you can simply do

```
string fullName = "foobar.domain";
string hostName = fullName.Substring(0, fullName.IndexOf('.'));
```

(With proper error checking of course, for the case that "fullName" is not actually a fullname).

Comment: Do you have any authoritative source that no hostnames can contain a dot?

Answer (score 5):

Out of a fqdn:

```
string s = "some.computer.name";
string host = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('.'));
```

Out of the framework:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the retrieved hostname from GetHostName() into by Split function, and the 0th item of the result array:

```
string s = "some.computer.name";
string host = s.Split('.')[0];
```