# how to find FQDN for any machine name in multi domain scenario

Tags: c#, cross-domain, fqdn

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/how-to-find-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c-net) for getting FQDN of localhost. My question is, is there any way to get the FQDN of machine which is not in same domain as host machine where we query in c#.

For eg: on machineA (in Domain A) runs a program to find out FQDN of machineB (in Domain B).

Answer (score 4):

In C# (.NET) you can call

```
var fqdn = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("host-name-goes-here").HostName
```

*Almost* the same for powershell

```
$fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("host-name-goes-here").HostName
```

Comment: Very useful, just a hint - if you want the FQDN of the current machine you can say: `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).HostName; `