# How to get the UNC / fully qualified name for the server running a service application

Tags: vb.net, service

I have a service application running on an application server. As part of that, I need to be able to identify the "full computer name" or UNC name of the server running the service.

So for example, I could use :

```
My.Computer.Name
```

Or

```
System.Environment.MachineName
```

But both of these just return the NETBIOS name i.e. **ABCD1234**

I want the fully qualified name recognisable across the network, i.e. **ABCD1234.mydomain.mysubdomain.com**

How can I achieve this easily in VB.NET, it seems like such a simple thing to retrieve but I can't find a method anywhere?

Thanks

Al

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/how-to-find-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c-net

Comment: I had not found the question above, but the code is the same for VB.
 My answer was, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name should give domain\user, if that helps? Another way is Environment.UserDomainName.

For the actual machine name, this works for me: System.Net.Dns.GetHostName

Comment: Thanks @MatSnow that was precisely what I was looking for - had googled every name and acronym for fully qualified paths under the sun apart from FQDN...